# Primefaces DataTable display only the last item

Tags: java, jpa, primefaces, datatable

the Datatable is displaying only the last item added, it seems that every time i press the commandButton the method rewrites the list, what can I do to avoid that?

JSF

```
 <p:commandButton  action="#{productoBean.setPedidoActual()}" value="Agregar" update="dt"/>

        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:dataTable value="#{productoBean.pedidoActual}" var="pedi">
            <p:column headerText="Nombre">                  
                <h:outputText  value="#{pedi.descripcion}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

Bean

```
public void setPedidoActual() {

    Producto pro = productoFacade.find(idProducto);

        listPedidoActual.add(pro);

}

public List<Producto> getPedidoActual() {

    return listPedidoActual;
}
```

Comment: What is the Scope of your Bean? If it is RequestScoped the Bean will be reconstructed on every click. If it is Session- or View Scoped it should keep the list content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setPedidoActual()` method seems like to receive only one item based on the facade service `find(idProducto)`, is that correct? Have you checked what the remote service returns? Probably there is in fact just one record.

Beside that, try to rename your setter/getter from

`getPedidoActual()` / `setPedidoActual()`

into

`getListPedidoActual()` `setListPedidoActual()`

Now your method names are consistent with your attribute.

EDIT: What happened to the panelGrid tag? Have you purposely omitted or where does it start?